There is an upper bound for a node and its neighbors that are completely disjoint from the neighbors of other nodes.
An undirected graph with N nodes, where $F(i)$ represents the set of adjacent nodes of $i$. Let $R(i_1, . . . , i_p)$ be an index with index i = $(i_1, . . . , i_p)\in \{1, . . . , N\}^p$, which means that there are N possibilities for each $i_l$. If $R(i_1, . . . , i_p) =1$, it means that there is an index $i_l$ such that $F(i_l)$ does not intersect with all other sets $\{F_{i_1},...,F_{i_p}\}$, otherwise $R(i_1, . . . , i_p) =0$. If any The $\max_i|F_i|\le K$, so how many combinations of $i$ are there to make $R(i_1, . . . , i_p)=0$? I hope to find his upper limit

Based on your definition, it seems to me whenever there are repeated elements in $i$, $R(i) = 0$. Is it intended?

Yes. Becaise each element of the sequence of $i$ may be the same
